# Is there a way to disable tree-shaking in webpack 2?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Is there a way in webpack 2 to either disable tree-shaking, or revert to the webpack 1 behavior where imports are handled by babel? I've got what appears to be a bug in webpack, but it only happens randomly (not 100% reproduceable) and I want to revert to the old behavior to see if the problem goes away.

The bug I am seeing is one where I do an import of a module in node_modules, and sometimes the resulting symbol is undefined. For example:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
```

The value 'withRouter' is undefined, but only in one module. Curiously, this only happens on initial build, if I do an incremental build everything works fine.

Note that setting `{ modules: true }` for babel doesn't work - it simply causes webpack to report an error.

I don't want to file this as a bug until I learn more. And because this only happens to one symbol out of thousands in a large project, I doubt that I can make a small repro case.

Edit: I created a minimalist example that can reproduce the problem:

https://github.com/viridia/webpack-miscompile

Comment: Did you happen to find a way to disable unused code removal? I am facing a similar problem, where I am building an npm package containing some modules that are meant to be used by other consumer libraries, but are not referenced in the npm package itself, so webpack excludes them from the output bundle.

Comment: I never got a response here, or to the github bug I filed with webpack. I'm having bad luck with stackoverflow lately, the vast majority of my questions go unanswered.

Comment: I hate to add a "me too" but... "me too".  Modules that are present in development mode are SOMETIMES not present in production.  Tree shaking seems to be to blame but I can't discern how to disable it...  At least to see if that is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my original problem that I was attempting to debug - see https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/876 for a full explanation. Basically I was using a callback option wrong in webpack-dev-server.

However, I never did discover if there was an option to disable tree-shaking.